# EF5 CodeFirst Migrations Customizations and DatabaseInitializers

Tags: entity-framework-5

Here is a weird behavior. Im trying to use one of the database initializers together with code first migrations.

I am using DropCreateDatabaseAlways and my "migrations code" is never called. Even using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion its not being called.

I have migrations enabled and one custom index for testing (I have changed the migrations file and manually added the index creation for one table).

When I use "Update-Database" from package manager console it works allright. The database gets created and the index is being added to the table.

When I use any DBInitializer, or let EF create the database (default), it creates the database without the index....

Any thoughts?

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Have you got EnableAutomaticMigrations=True ? that seems to prevent the Initial migration getting created, then EF does not run the migrations, it takes some sort of short cut to creating the database.

If you would like to run your migrations in code, you can do so...

```
        //create a migrator and migrate your database
        var connectionInfo =
            new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
                .DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
        //new up your auto-created Migrations Configuration class
        var config = new Context.Migrations.Configuration();
        config.TargetDatabase = connectionInfo;
        //new up a Migrator
        var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations
            .DbMigrator(config);
        var pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();


        if (pendingMigrations.Any())
        {
            migrator.Update();
            var ctx2 = new CloudMinderDataContext(connectionString);
            //YourSeedMethodHere(ctx2);                
        }
```

http://softwaremechanik.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/ef6-if-migrations-are-enabled-cannot-createdatabaseifnotexists/